# Retrieve nsdata from sqlite stored in Blob data type for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, blob, nsdata

In iPhone App how to store `UIImage` converted into NSData to sqlite table in BLOB datatype?
Is there any kind of binding needed(`NSData` ->Blob)?

or

While retrieving image stored in `NSData` form in sqlite Blob datatype,
should I need to perform any task to convert that stored database in blob datatype to get back into `NSData` form?

Please help and suggest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used something like this:

```
// prepare sqlite3 statement before this line
int res = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if (res == SQLITE_ROW) {
    const void *ptr = sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 0);
    int size = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 0);
    data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:ptr length:size];
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);

    return [data autorelease];
} 
sqlite3_reset(stmt);
```

For saving as blob you can extract pointer and size of NSData using `[data bytes]` and `[data length]`. And then bind to your BLOB row

```
sqlite3_bind_blob (stmt, 2, [data bytes], [data length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```