# How to save NSMutable Array details in any database for iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have successfully implemented SQLite in my app and it is working perfectly fine, retrieving and storing data is working, however i have one issue, in one of my Classes there are almost 9 arrays, which are storing data coming from web services and displaying on UITableView, i need to make storing for that Array in database, i have tried with SQLite however it doesn't work, because array cannot be stored in that. Please help me with this

Comment: can u please give a code which u use to store in array??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this before thinking to save lots of data into plist: [Should I save in plist or Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964408/should-i-save-in-plist-or-core-data)

Besides storing it in a plist you basically have two alternatives.

You need to write them one by one in separate entries in a SQLite DB or store them also one by one with core data.

You may check this for more core data details [Best practice? - Array/Dictionary as a Core Data Entity Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562676/best-practice-array-dictionary-as-a-core-data-entity-attribute)

For a related topic see here [Store NSMutable Array into sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391820/store-nsmutable-array-into-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 1):

Try saving it in a **plist** in the documentsDirectory of the project ,because plist supports datatypes like array,dictionaries