# how to retrieve NSdata into NSdictionary from Sqlite in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsdictionary, nsdata

I am creating `iOS` app which uses Sqlite DB.
I have created `Table` As:

```
const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDERTABLE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ITEMDESC TEXT)";
```

and then I have to insert self.selectedItemsDictnory Dictionary into ItemDESC
i am inserting as :

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.selectedItemsDictnory options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO ORDERTABLE(ITEMDESC)VALUES( \"%@\");",data];
```

Upto this it is successfully done.

Now i have to retrieve this dictionary in same format

what i am doing is :

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &orderDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {            
        const char* sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ORDERTABLE WHERE (ID = '%d')",self.orderSelected]cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        sqlite3_stmt* statement;

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(orderDB, sqlStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {


                if( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
                {

               NSData *retData = (__bridge NSData*) sqlite3_column_value(statement, 1);
               NSDictionary *jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
                                              JSONObjectWithData:retData
                                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                              error:nil];
                    NSLog(@"jsonObject is %@",jsonObject);
                    NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfData:retData];
                    NSLog(@"dic is %@",dic);

                }
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(orderDB);
        }
```

---

But i am getting Bad Excess Exception.
Please help me out in retrieval of data

Comment: Can you point out exact line where you are getting an exception?

Comment: hi ,i am getting exception at 
                    NSDictionary *jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
                                              JSONObjectWithData:retData
                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                            error:nil];

Comment: i think it is not nil, when i PO
its displaying as 
$1 = 0x090c71a8 [no Objective-C description available]

Comment: since id is integer type , remove quotes in the id ,SELECT * FROM ORDERTABLE WHERE (ID = %d) and try

Comment: hey karthik removing quotes is not helping  any thing .. 
:(

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible if you can paste JSON here. Return type of `NSJSONSerialization` could be a Dictionary or an Array it depends on the root json object.

instead of

```
NSDictionary *jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:retData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                          error:nil];
```

Try

```
NSArray *jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:retData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                          error:nil];
```

And also its good habit to use error parameter to register for any exception so you can use

```
NSError *logError = nil;
NSArray *jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:retData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                          error:&error];
```

Comment: actually in my selected item dictionary there are key/value pair
like  {
    Pasta = 220;
    "Spring Rolls" = 125;
}

it is a restrain waiter App
in which while taking order i am saving items with price in dictionary and then inserting in sqlite order table with nsdata

Comment: I think you should go through this tutorial, hope it might help http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to fetch data from sqlite

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
 {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        int uniqueId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        char * temp = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);  
        NSString *item_desc = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:temp];                                  
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Comment: hi karthik 
i got result in item_desc 
 as po item_desc
$1 = 0x0715c6f0 <7b0a2020 224d4f4d 4f277322 203a2022 31323522 2c0a2020 22537072 696e6720 526f6c6c 7322203a 20223132 35220a7d>


so how will i convert this into my actually dictionary???

Comment: As you need to insert nsdata to the column ITEMDESC, declare type of ITEMDESC as BLOB, pls refer    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724118/retrieve-nsdata-from-sqlite-stored-in-blob-data-type-for-iphone-app ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215505/sqlite3-insert-and-read-blob-data-in-database

Comment: hi Karthik , i have declare data type of ITEM_DESC as blob, 
now how to convert string item_desc into nsditionary again

Comment: convert nsdictionary into nsdata and use sqlite3_bind_blob , for conversion refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157356/converting-nsdictionary-object-to-nsdata-object-and-vice-versa

Comment: karthik , this process can only convert to NSdictionary , if it was archived.

Comment: have you tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215505/sqlite3-insert-and-read-blob-data-in-database, to insert nsdata into sqlite.

Comment: now i have created table as .
const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDERTABLE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ITEMDESC BLOB)";